# Browse pdf with IText (or Itextsharp)

Tags: itext

I'm receiving a pdf that contains some data I would like to parse.

For example, there's an array with some integer data that I would like to parse for an automatic treatment.

I've looked at itext but the sample I've found are for writing pdf only.

Can someone give me an example of how to read through a pdf ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best regards

Comment: Is this data text on the pages, or an actual integer array embedded in the PDF?

Comment: I don't know. All I see when opening the pdf is that it has some interesting data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, 
I'm converting PDF to Word and I'm using Word interop :)

Answer (score 0):

[PdfBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is much better for reading text from a PDF file.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've looked at the getText method. The text extacted is not exact and without any way to parse it. How can I read line to line and extract chunk ?